# Create track motion app in iOS

Tags: ios, gps, latitude-longitude, indoor-positioning-system

I just want some hint of how can I create an app in iOS which can do following.

When a user is at point X, user will click on start button so app will start a timer and track the movement. User will be on a horse and user needs to ride in a full circle. When user comes back to point X the app should draw the route taken by the user on the horse.

> Aim is to ride completely in a circle. I want to make this app to
>   practice and see how close to a circle I ride.

I tried to look at GPS locator but I am not sure whether it will give me efficient results because the circle I ride can be as small as **60m or less** in radius.

I don't know if iOS GPS can be this accurate. I read article on motion sensor and how to track rotation and acceleration.

But I am not quite sure how to use that to my advantage.

I just need some tips like which API to use etc.

Comment: GPS can not give you accurate result in small range. EX. try to get current location and stay in one place all time you get different lat. long.   for this solution use approximate lat long near by and check round is completed or not.

Comment: @HarshilKotecha sorry i didnt get how can i make the app? I should not use GPS right? so which API should i use???

Comment: Google Map api is best. can I give tutorial and link for  how to start learning?

Comment: @HarshilKotecha i thought of that but is the lat and lang given by GPS is accurate enough to track my positioning?

Comment: not perfect accurate result. give variance 1 or 2 m .

Comment: http://www.montana.edu/gps/understd.html

Comment: Using the Standard Positioning Service one can achieve 15 meter horizontal accuracy 95% of the time. This means that 95% of the time, the coordinates you read from your GPS receiver display will be within 15 meters of your true position on the earth.

Comment: @HarshilKotecha yeah i read that but in my case 15m is too big margin of error. Horse ride circle can be 40m to 50m in radius and 15m margin of error will not give me appropriate data to correct myself and train the horse. Maximum 1m margin of error can be understandable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142304/discussion-between-harshil-kotecha-and-mike-ross).

Comment: Please check Chat

Answer (score 0):

> Using the Standard Positioning Service one can achieve 15 meter
>   horizontal accuracy 95% of the time. This means that 95% of the time,
>   the coordinates you read from your GPS receiver display will be within
>   15 meters of your true position on the earth.
>
> More Information [click here](http://montana.edu/gps/understd.html)

For integrate Map and draw path using current position  google map is good option for integrate in iOS mobile .

**small and range and get accurate result use indoor position system.**

For more information about Indoor positioning system (IPS) [**click here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtBERi7Lf3c)
http://developer.estimote.com/

and Github iOS demo : [**get code**](https://github.com/harshilkotecha/beacon-platform)